# Switching activity on server response

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am making a login activity which takes two parameters id and password.
I get it check by a php API on server , which response Success on correct login credentials.  I want to switch the activity if i have text = "Success" on my textview(named result) , its not working.
I also tried it by keeping the check after requestqueue add below (comment) , still doesn't work.
If my approach is incorrect please suggest me the easiest possible way to achieve this task.

```
package com.example.nigam.quiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        final EditText userid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button startq= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final String url="http://192.168.44.223/Quiz/login.php";
        final RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final JSONObject jsonObject = new  JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("userid",userid.getText().toString());
                    jsonObject.put("password",password.getText().toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                       result.setText(response.toString());

                       if(result.getText().toString()=="Success")
                       {
                           Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Begins.class);
                           startActivity(i);
                       }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                })
                {
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        parameters.put("creden",jsonObject.toString());
                        return parameters;

                    }

                };

                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                /*
                 if(result.getText().toString()=="Success")
                       {
                           Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Begins.class);
                           startActivity(i);
                       }
                 */

            }
        });

        startq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Begins.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What happens when you run your app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Why not compare `response`? You don't need to set an TextView when you are immediately starting a new Activity with that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use .equals() to compare strings.

Comment: but i would like to understand the reason . how is "==" different from .equals?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java